# Curl requests to Appium

Tags: curl, appium

Previously used **Appium** version **1.4.13**. During the running session on the Android device on the request:

```
curl -N http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/status
```

received the response:

```
{"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}},"sessionId":"29b3c645-a825-404a-aded-d3c97717abad"}
```

Updated on the **Appium 1.6.5**. Now the same request get the response:

```
{"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.6.5","revision":null}},"sessionId":null}
```

It does not matter is now going session or not!

First of all, I'm interested in knowing the **sessionId**. Or some other pointer to the fact that the test session is currently running.
Perhaps there are other CURL requests to the Appium server? I would like to have a **complete list of CURL requests to the Appium**. Or maybe the requests have changed for the new version Appium 1.6.5?

Sorry for bad english.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I think session ID is returned only if any runs are happening. Try the same when you are already running a test.